# TSQL 'Lookup' Function - Confused

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, vlookup

I've been working on a 'simple' problem all day and its driving me mad. I'm sure I am missing something obvious; however no amount of searching is helping me.

I have a 1 row data table such as; (Table_1)

```
             Person_1          Person_2         Person_3
PersonID        ABC               DEF              GHI
```

However I need to replace the references with values from another table but matching with the ID column, such as; (Table_2)

```
PersonID      Work_Done
  LMN            298
  GHI            187
  ABC            872
  XYZ            468
  DEF            512
```

Therefore returning;

```
             Person_1          Person_2         Person_3
Work_Done      872               512              187
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition V8.00.2039 and I have no control over my source tables.

Any help (even just ideas on what to Google) would be really appreciated.

SQL to generate example tables;

```
-- Table_1
SELECT
'ABC' AS Person_1,
'DEF' AS Person_2,
'GHI' AS Person_3
;
-- Table_2
SELECT 'LMN' AS Person_ID, 298 AS Work_Done
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI' AS Person_ID, 187 AS Work_Done
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC' AS Person_ID, 872 AS Work_Done
UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ' AS Person_ID, 468 AS Work_Done
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF' AS Person_ID, 512 AS Work_Done
;
--Returning
SELECT
'872' AS Person_1,
'512' AS Person_2,
'187' AS Person_3;
```

Comment: (1) Table_1 seems to be confused about rows/columns.  (2) The sql you're giving at the end is not creating tables.  I can tell you that you're looking for a join, but I'm afraid that might not be helpful enough.  Check out a sql tutorial, eg. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't change the design, here's the code to retrieve what you want:

```
SELECT Person_1 = a.Work_Done
, Person_2 = b.Work_Done
, Person_3 = c.Work_Done
FROM Table1 t
   JOIN Table2 a ON t.Person_1 = a.Person_ID
   JOIN Table2 b ON t.Person_2 = b.Person_ID
   JOIN Table2 c ON t.Person_3 = c.Person_ID
```

Multiple joins to aliases of the same table (Table2)

Comment: Nice and simple, although the actual data table has 9 columns so I will need 9 joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  unpvt.Person_Type, b.Work_Done
    FROM    Table_1 a
    UNPIVOT ( Person_ID FOR Person_Type IN (a.[Person_1], a.[Person_2], a.[Person_3]) ) unpvt
    JOIN    Table_2 b ON unpvt.Person_ID = b.Person_ID
) c
PIVOT   ( MAX(c.Work_Done) FOR c.Person_Type IN ([Person_1], [Person_2], [Person_3]) ) pvt
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26644)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

DO PIVOT
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

PLEASE NOTE that you need to use embedded SQL and EXEC @sql  if you want to have different combinations

please note that in     FOR Person_ID IN ([ABC], [DEF],[LMN],[GHI],[XYZ])
[ABC] is the colum of the table you need to be careful with ' apostrophes when you do you @sql

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM(

SELECT 'LMN' AS Person_ID,  298   AS Work_Done 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI' AS Person_ID, 187 AS Work_Done  
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC' AS Person_ID, 872 AS Work_Done 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ' AS Person_ID, 468 AS Work_Done 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF' AS Person_ID, 512 AS Work_Done 


) as datasourcetable
PIVOT
(
 SUM(Work_Done ) 
FOR Person_ID IN ([ABC], [DEF],[LMN],[GHI],[XYZ])

) AS PivotTable;
```